# How to make a list of stacks in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I'm trying to make a list of stacks in C++ using the code below , but I'm getting the error

```
main.cpp:17:13: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka class std::stack}’ has no member named ‘push_back’
 vs[i-1].push_back(s);
```

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<stack<int>> vs;

for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
stack<int> s;
s.push(i*2);
s.push(i*3);
s.push(i*4);
vs[i-1].push_back(s);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: By doing ```vs[i-1]``` you are indexing the vector that stores stacks. Stacks don't have ```push_back()```.

Comment: Please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.). And please learn how to *indent* your code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use this line:-

```
vs[i-1].push_back(s);
```

Either define the size of the list earlier.
For Eg

```
vector<stack<int> > vs(100);
```

else only write

```
vs.push_back(s);
```

Updated Solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    vector< stack<int> > vs;
 
for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
{
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(i*2);
    s.push(i*3);
    s.push(i*4);
    vs.push_back(s);
}
 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your vector is *empty*, any indexing in it will be out of bounds and lead to undefined behavior.

Secondly, `vs[any_valid_index]` is a *stack* and not a vector.

What you probably want is

```
vs.push_back(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a fact for only vector of stacks. It is actually basic property of vector. You have two options to add value into vector.

1. If you don't declare size of vector (what you did) like

   ```
    vector<stack<int>> vs;
    stack<int>s;
   ```

Then you can insert by using `vs.push_back(s)` It will automatically handle the index.

2. Another way is you can declare the size of the vector first. like

   ```
   vector<stack<int>> vs(sz); //size(sz) is defined by user
   stack<int>s;
   ```

Then you can insert by using `vs[index]= s` This time you have to manually handle the index.